# C# - Intersection between Lists of IComparable objects

Tags: c#, collections

How would one find the intersecting objects from two lists of objects that all implements IComparable?

```
public List<T> Intersect<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) where T : IComparable<T> {
    return ... ;
}
```

Comment: Well, have you tried anything yet? One fairly simple option would be to create an `IEqualityComparer` which used `CompareTo` to check for equality, and then just use LINQ's `Intersect` method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
public List<T> Intersetc<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return list1.Intersect(list2, new MyEqualityComparer<T>()).ToList();
}

public class MyEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T t1, T t2)
    {
        return t1.CompareTo(t2) == 0;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T t)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible that `GetHashCode` return different values and still `CompareTo` returns 0

Comment: That's true. Updated the answer.

Comment: What I meant is that there are some cases where `t1.CompareTo(t2) == 0`, but `MyEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode()` returns different values and thus `MyEqualityComparer<T>.Equals` will not be called.

Comment: Just checked the implementation of Intersect, and you are right. The code won't return expected result in that case.

Comment: If you return a constant value (e.g. 0) in `MyEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode`, you will force `MyEqualityComparer<T>.Equals` to be called everytime.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
    public List<T> Intersect<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        var intersect = list1.Intersect(list2);
        return intersect.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: It does not use IComparable<T> for comparison.